# Send email notifications to users while specifying their names and expiration date of their certificate

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I want to send email notifications to users whose certificates will expire soon. The code below allows me to send an email to each email address selected in MySQL. I want to select at the same time email and expiration date to send notifications.

```
#!/bin/bash
EMAIL_ADDRESS="mysql -N -uUser -pPassword database -e \
"SELECT email FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(date_expiration, CURDATE()) <=30 AND date_expiration > CURDATE()" 
echo  "Hello! The expiration date of your certificate is [date_expiration] ,please follow the procedure to renew it" \
| mailx -A gmail -s "Certificate expiration date" $EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

Comment: I doubt this code does anything. Why did you word wrap the code?

Comment: This code is already sending emails to users? I tested it. But I would like to add the expiration date. Sorry if I did not edit my question, I'm a beginner. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r N E D ; do
    echo  "Hello $N, The expiration date of your certificate for $D is nearing, please renew it" \
    | mailx -A gmail -s "Certificate expiration date" "$N <$E>"
done < <(mysql -N -uUser -pPassword database -e \
"SELECT name, email, domain FROM users, certs WHERE domain.user=user.id and DATEDIFF(date_expiration, CURDATE()) <=30 AND date_expiration > CURDATE()" )
```

Comment: Thanks user1133275 for your  prompt answer! Let me try it.

Comment: This is the actual code based on your post. No errors but not sending mails

Comment: #!/bin/bash USERS=`mysql -N -uUser -pPassword database -e \
"SELECT nom, email, date  FROM users WHERE DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE()) <=30 AND date > CURDATE()"` while read -r N E D ; do
    echo  "Hello $N, The expiration date of your certificate for $D is nearing, please renew it" \
    | mailx -A gmail -s "Certificate expiration date" "$E <$E>"
done << $USERS